# How to access a Name that is value in JSON in C#

Tags: c#, json

currently I have this:

```
{
  "example" :{
    "001":{
      "ID":"001",
      "Name":"Test1"  
    },
    "002":{
      "ID": "002",
      "Name": "test2"
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to access the Name,but so far I have this code:

```
   DataRow x = dtNew.NewRow();
   Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject obj =  Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(testing);
   x["Name"] = jobj2["example"]["????"]["Name"].ToString();
```

The `["001"]` part depends on the ID

Comment: First, you need to understand that this JSON is not valid.

Comment: Use http://jsonlint.com/ to check JSON is valid or not

Comment: it is valid, I just can't access the x["Name"] =

Comment: What you can do is to Generate Classes out of your JSON and use it http://www.codingdefined.com/2015/03/generating-c-classes-from-xml-or-json.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing you need to understand is that your JSON is invalid.
You can use [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com) to check if your JSON is valid.
JSON should be an **object** or an **array**.

The valid JSON object will be:

```
{
    "example": {
        "001": {
            "ID": "001",
            "Name": "Test1"
        },
        "002": {
            "ID": "002",
            "Name": "test2"
        }
    }
}
```

After these changes this works for me:

```
DataRow x = dtNew.NewRow();
var obj = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(testing);
x["Name"] = jobj2["example"]["001"]["Name"].ToString();
```

**Update 1**: The OP has fixed his JSON object, the question has changed.

Actually, it is an another question. How to parse JSON object with dynamic sub-object name.

There are several ways to do this. I would recommend to declare classes and parse this JSON object as a `Dictionary` this way:

```
public class Response
{
    public Dictionary<string, ExampleObj> example { get; set; }
}

public class ExampleObj {
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

// Somewhere in code

string jsonString = "{\"example\" :{ \"001\":{ \"ID\":\"001\", \"Name\":\"Test1\" }, \"002\":{ \"ID\": \"002\", \"Name\": \"test2\" }}}";

var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(jsonString);

foreach (var keyValuePair in obj.example)
{
    Console.WriteLine("That's a {0}", keyValuePair.Key);
    Console.WriteLine("It's name is {0}", keyValuePair.Value.Name);
}
```

`JsonConvert` will recognize this dynamic name "????" (for example, '001') as a dynamic `Dictionary` key - and it's content will be serialized to a `Dictionary` value of `ExampleObj` class.

Here is a working [DotNetFiddle Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UfqYlN).

Comment: But how would I make it dynamic?

Comment: @TomJerry What do you mean by dynamic?

Comment: x["Name"] = jobj2["example"]["001"]["Name"].ToString(); // the ["001"] part is only declared, which means I cannot access it dynamically

Comment: I'm not familiar in c# my suggestion for(int i=1;i<3;i++){ Console.WriteLine(obj["example"]["00"+i]["Name"]); }

Comment: @JarachanthanRatnakumar it is good but it will only be limited to the example, how about if the ID is 12131212?

Comment: actually it is 11 random numbers :)