# How to parse JSON object with dynamic sub-object name in c#

Tags: c#, json

I'd already asked in this :[sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30907156/how-to-access-a-name-that-is-value-in-json-in-c-sharp)

but now I have a different format of the json:

```
{
  "response": "success",
  "example" :{
       "001":{
            "ID":"001",
            "Name":"Test1"  
        },
       "002":{
            "ID": "002",
            "Name": "test2"
       }
   },
  "reference": "google.com"
}
```

my question again is how can I access the `Name`:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is to add a couple of `string` members to your `Response` class.

Mostly, the code hasn't changed at all.
You even could parse this object using the previous code - you just would lose  `response` and `reference` values.

```
public class Response
{
    public string response { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, ExampleObj> example { get; set; }
    public string reference { get; set;}
}

public class ExampleObj {
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

// Somewhere in code

string jsonString = "{ \"response\": \"success\", \"example\" :{ \"001\":{ \"ID\":\"001\", \"Name\":\"Test1\" }, \"002\":{ \"ID\": \"002\", \"Name\": \"test2\" } }, \"reference\": \"google.com\"}";

var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(jsonString);

foreach (var keyValuePair in obj.example)
{
    Console.WriteLine("That's a {0}", keyValuePair.Key);
    Console.WriteLine("It's name is {0}", keyValuePair.Value.Name);
}

Console.WriteLine("And, Hey! That's a reference '{0}' and response '{1}'", obj.reference, obj.response);
```

I hope that you are not going to ask a question every time you need to add a single variable to a class. You should try to understand it yourself: read documentation, google for specific theory questions but not pracical solutions, try to do this yourself. That's the only way to become a software engineer.